# HTML indents not working with PHP include

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, doctype

I wrote a small MVC app for a small website I am working on. I created a load method that loads the header, footer, and the specified view file. I am having issues to where the header is not loading all of the JS files and the entire document's HTML structure is missing indents.

Header.php:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title><?php echo $meta['title']; ?></title>

   <?php //load all of the css files
        foreach (glob("layout/css/*.css") as $css_filename)
            { 
              echo  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.INSTALL_PATH.'/'.$css_filename.'">';
            }


        //load all of the js files 
        foreach (glob("layout/js/*.js") as $js_filename)
            { 
              echo '<script src="'.INSTALL_PATH.'/'.$js_filename.'"></script>';
            }


        ?>
</head>
<body>
```

Renders as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang=en> 
<head> 
<meta charset=utf-8> 
<title>Test Title</title> 
<link rel=stylesheet href="/labs/wpsm/layout/css/style.css"><script></script></head> 
<body>
```

One weird thing that I discovered is that if I include random text before the doctype declaration, everything is back to normal.

With extra character:

```
 s
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Test Title</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/labs/wpsm/layout/css/style.css"><script src="/labs/wpsm/layout/js/test.js"></script></head>
    <body>
```

What am I missing here? I checked the character encoding of the page and it is utf-8. Any help or pointers would be awesome!

Comment: What happens if you take out all of the PHP?

Comment: I don't really care about the HTML indents but that issue also corresponds to my JS file being included. Notice in the first render that the JS file is missing. In the second render all I did was add the letter "s" before the doctype.

Comment: The weird part is that the first output contained `<script></script>`. Looking at your code, that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Yea, pretty sure there's something else going on here.

Comment: Ya that is what has me so confused. The PHP is outputting the src attribute but the rendered page is not showing it, that is why I think it must me some crazy doctype or character encoding issue that is leaving it out.

Comment: @ssergei: Or caching, or something's changing in the code that actually pulls this file up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out as I was messing around with the server. I discovered that it had mod_pagespeed enabled, I disabled the mod_pagespeed module (Google Page Speed for Apache) and it fixed the indenting and the JS file starting working. The module was automatically removing  the JS file because it was a blank file I had put into the directory just to make sure the PHP was pulling the files properly. Thank you everyone for the help and I hope this helps someone save a few fistfuls of hair.